# How to use std::accumulate over first 3 values of map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

I want to use `std::accumulate` on a `map<int,int>` just on the first 3 elements of the map. This does not work, could you point my mistake ?

```
int main(){
    map<int, int> m;
    m[1] = 1;
    m[2] = 2;
    m[3] = 4;
    m[4] = 8;
    struct pair_add {
      int operator()(int i, const std::pair<int, int>& x) {
        return i + x.second;
      }
    };
    int cumSumQty = accumulate(m.begin(), m.end, 0, pair_add()); //THIS COMPILE
    int cumSumQty = accumulate(m.begin(), m.begin()+3, 0, pair_add()); //THIS DOES NOT
}
```

Comment: map has no random access iterator

Comment: So to do what I want I need to loop through the map correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map doesn't have random access iterators, you cannot use `+` with it.

Use `std::advance` as:

```
auto it = m.begin();
std::advance(it,3);
int cumSumQty = accumulate(m.begin(), it , 0, pair_add());
```

Or, better use `std::next` as:

```
int cumSumQty = accumulate(m.begin(), std::next(m.begin(), 3) , 0, pair_add());
```

Since `std::map::iterator` is `BidirectionalIterator`, so you can do even this:

```
int cumSumQty = accumulate(std::next(m.end(),-3), m.end(), 0, pair_add());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice, and to go from end-3 to end can I do `int cumSumQty = accumulate(std::advance(m.end(),-3), m.end(), 0, pair_add()); ` ??

Comment: @statquant: Yes. you can go backward also. `std::map::iterator` is `BidirectionalIterator`, so `-3` is allowed. Just note that `std::advance` returns `void`,  so you cannot call it like that. See my answer.

Comment: If I do not put `auto` `advance` does not work, but `next` do... `J:\\C++\STLtest\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
J:\\C++\STLtest\main.cpp|92|error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::map<int, int>::iterator'|
c:\mingw32-xy\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator_base_funcs.h|169|error: in passing argument 1 of 'void std::advance(_InputIterator&, _Distance) [with _InputIterator ...
`(next is C++11 though) why is that ?

Comment: @statquant: Yes, for `auto` you have to use C++11. If you're using GCC to compile your code, then use `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: @Nawaz not `std::next(m.begin() + 3)`, but `std::next(m.begin(), 3)`

Comment: @lip: That was typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @Nawaz, I am using `-c0x` but `advance` does not work if I do not `it` as `auto` aka `int cumSumQty = accumulate(m.begin(), std::advance(m.begin(),3), 0, pair_add());` does not work

Comment: @statquant: `std::advance` returns `void`. You understand what it means?

Comment: @Nawaz: no :( I can look for it if too long to explain

Comment: @statquant: Please do so. Don't *only* write code. Understand them also - each and every bit of them.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` iterators are not random access, so this

```
m.begin() + 3
```

is illegal. You can use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead:

```
std::next(m.begin(), 3);
```

Usage:

```
int cumSumQty = accumulate(m.begin(), std::next(m.begin(), 3), 0, pair_add());
```

Comment: @hetepeperfan sorry, I can't make any sense out of your question!

Comment: @juanchopanza Well the OP want to accumulate ints in the order they were added to `std::map< std::int, std::int >`, and he/she wants the first three ints. What I was wondering if the map had been `std::map < std::string, std::int >` (sorry my mistake in the first comment) I was wondering whether this approach also works when a string is the key of the map. Does one accumulate the first three values in the order they are added. or in the order they are inside the map, or are pairs stored in the map in the order they are added?

Comment: @hetepeperfan OP doesn't mention anything about the insertion order, just the order the elements happen to be in, which is determined by the `int` key. The map doesn't know anything about the insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::advance. std::map's iterators are not random-access iterators, so adding an offset doesn't work. However, I'd also consider writing a simple for loop or maybe even just spelling it out for the three elements.